# MS BOT Framework (adaptive cards): How to send value (Stepcontext.Value) from directline

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I have deployed a Bot in Azure, the Bot displays a welcome message OnMemberAdd. Its adaptive card so the entered value are sent to stepcontext.value. I have integrated it with multiple channels, for directline, I would like to bypass the welcome card and pass the message directly to stepcontext.value so the second prompt is displayed instead of first. I have tried the below but it does not work, please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Send welcome event</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat"></div>
    <script>
      (async function() {
        // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
        // Your client code must provide either a secret or a token to talk to your bot.
        // Tokens are more secure. To learn about the differences between secrets and tokens
        // and to understand the risks associated with using secrets, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

        const { token } = { token};

        // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
        const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
 if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
   dispatch({
     type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
     payload: { 
                name: 'userInfo',
       value: { fname:'user', lname:'test', pnumber:'0678775453'} 
                }
   });
 }

 return next(action);
        });

        const styleOptions = {
 botAvatarImage:
   '',
 botAvatarInitials: 'Chatbot',
 userAvatarImage: '',
 userAvatarInitials: 'User',
 showNub: true,
 bubbleFromUserNubOffset: 'bottom',
 bubbleFromUserNubSize: 10,
 bubbleFromUserBorderColor: '#0077CC',
 bubbleNubOffset: 'top',
 bubbleNubSize: 0,
 bubbleBorderColor: '#009900',
 sendBoxButtonColor: '#009900',
 hideUploadButton: true,
 hideSendBox : true
        };
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
 {
   directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
   store,
            styleOptions
 },
 document.getElementById('webchat')
        );

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to send the data via postman and it works well but when I do it using above code it does not work.

Postman body

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "value": 
    {
        "fname":"user",
        "lname":"test",
        "pnumber":"0678787543"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it does not work"? You currently have it set up to send that message as soon as WebChat connects to the bot, which I don't believe is what you're looking for. Or are you saying that the message is not going through at all?

Comment: I am using a HTML / Java Script template from MS Web Chat examples . I am able to send the message as text, which is stepcontext.context.activity.text but in my case the bot is expecting data in stepcontext.context.activity.value.  So i am trying to send the data in value but the message does not reach the bot. I have tried the same step using postman and it works. I am looking for a  answer to understand how to send data to stepcontext.context.activity.value. please let me know if more information is required..

Comment: To add to the above, I would like to send the values as soon as the webchat is connected. I have tried to debug but not abe to identify why the message does not reach Chatbot when I send the values in payload, I dont see any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close! You have two options:

1. Change to `WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT` and include the `name` property:

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
          if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            dispatch({
              type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
              payload: {
                name: 'userInfo',
                value: { fname:'user', lname:'test', pnumber:'0678775453'}
              }
            });
          }

          return next(action);
        });
```

2. Use `WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE`, include the `text` property, and change to `channelData`:

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
          if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            dispatch({
              type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
              payload: {
                text: 'userInfo',
                channelData: { fname:'user', lname:'test', pnumber:'0678775453'}
              }
            });
          }

          return next(action);
        });
```

===

#### Update

I can see it coming through just fine using your code. Put a breakpoint in `onTurn`/`OnTurnAsync` and you'll see that when a user connects you get:

1. conversationUpdate for the bot
2. conversationUpdate for the user
3. WebChat's Event with the user data you want:

[image]

Comment: I have tried both the above options, I couldn't get it to work. It's not showing any errors but the data is not reaching the Bot. I am not sure if I am missing something. 1) ```var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.Value``` 2) ```var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData```

Comment: @KrishnaS Can you please update your question with your full `html` (minus the secrets)?

Comment: @KrishnaS I've updated my answer to show that your code behaves as expected/desired.